# An entityFilter (not equal) doesn't work correctly when user can choose more than one option

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

EntityFilter works well when you can select only one option but in my case, I allow the user to choose severals option :
[image: EntityFilter with more than one option]

Now if I filter by `not equal James Harveyd` this is my result :

[image]

And the way I add my filter :

```php
 public function configureFilters(Filters $filters): Filters
    {

        return $filters
            ->add(EntityFilter::new('supervisors', 'supervisors'));
    }
```

I don(t understand why EA make appear the second line, any idea ?

Comment: (I did not downvote), is your field `Responsables` an array type ? (maybe add how you add your filter and your entity property)

Comment: I just edited it